# Plumber Broke A Wire Doing Repairs, Can I Charge Them for Electrical Work?

Tags: wiring, contractors

Much like the title of the questions says; my HOA had to have a plumber come out to replace the risers for the building.

After they finished, I noticed that half my unit was without power.

Electricians came out and found that a wire inside of my conduit was broken. The wire appeared to have been pulled too hard and snapped (this is a little bit of conjecture, we can certainly say the wire was not cut). The total cost for the electricians to come out, identify the broken wire and replace it was ~2,000.00 for me.

Can/should I bill the HOA or the plumbers for the repair work that needed to be done to me wire?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because contract disputes are off-topic

Comment: You might have handled those details before you hired the electrician.  At this point you are saying "because of you..." And will need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

First off....WOW! Two grand to troubleshoot and repair a broken wire? That's sounds waaay high. That should cover a Journeyman electrician for a week. I think they based their price on the value of your home.

Second, if everything was working fine prior to the plumbers visit I would definitely ask for a back charge from your HOA.

Good luck!